# Reading the last 50 characters of a file with fseek()

Tags: c, file, fseek

I'm trying to read the last 50 characters in a file by doing this:

```
FILE* fptIn;
char sLine[51];
if ((fptIn = fopen("input.txt", "rb")) == NULL) {
    printf("Coudln't access input.txt.\n");
    exit(0);
}
if (fseek(fptIn, 50, SEEK_END) != 0) {
    perror("Failed");
    fclose(fptIn);
    exit(0);
}
fgets(sLine, 50, fptIn);
printf("%s", sLine);
```

This doesn't return anything that makes sense remotely. Why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change 50 to -50. Also note that this will only work with fixed-length character encodings like ASCII. Finding the 50th character from the end is far from trivial with things like UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the offset to -50.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the sign of the offset the following things could make trouble:

A newline character makes fgets stop reading, but it is considered a valid character and therefore it is included in the string copied to str.

Use either ferror or feof to check whether an error happened or the End-of-File was reached.

[See also](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/)

Answer (score 0):

> fseek(fptIn, 50, SEEK_END)

Sets the stream pointer at the end of the file, and then tries to position the cursor 50 bytes ahead thereof. Remember, for binary streams:

> **3** For a binary stream, the new position, measured in characters from the beginning of the file, is obtained by adding offset to the position specified by whence..The specified
>   position is the beginning of the file if whence is SEEK_SET, the current value of the file
>   position indicator if SEEK_CUR, or end-of-file if SEEK_END. **A binary stream need not
>   meaningfully support fseek calls with a whence value of SEEK_END.**

This call should fail. The next call to `fgets` invokes UB. Try -50 as an offset and also iff the call succeeds try to read it into your buffer

> Note: emphasis mine